# Is filesize/stat consistent across all filesystems?

Tags: file, filesystems, cross-platform, filesize, stat

I am considering writing software which uses the filesize as pretest to test whether two files are equivalent. There is no need to apply sophisticated file content comparisons if a simple file size integer comparison fails. The software is going to written in [golang](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) (first), but I think this question really boils down to the [stat syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) and therefore is language independent.

I necessarily need a platform-independent solution. It has to work across all systems and file systems. I can be sure that the file content will be the same sequence of bytes across all filesystems, but what about the filesize?

*If I transfer a file from one filesystem to another, can I be sure to get the same filesize on the other filesystem?*

[Of course, I don't care about file metadata. This is obviously inconsistent. I only care about content sizes]

Comment: It worth noting that not all tools measure the file size. Some measure the disk usage (ex: du) which may be different and which can be misleading when not look carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `st_size` should be the same across all filesystems (at least if they are posix compliant). A byte is a byte after all, no matter where you store it. The disk space consumed can be different though, depending on the underlying block size of the filesystem.

Comment: @meisterluk Does that answer your question? If yes, I await the bounty. :)

Comment: I am still tracking this issue. Your answer is the same common sense answer I came up with. If there are no better answers coming in until Tuesday, you will get the bounty.